# Optimizing my query on two very large tables

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have 2 tables 1st table name cjfeeds another name is linkshare my 2 tables contain upto 40 Million records. so my select query takes 12 to 15 minutes for fetching my single record .

Here's the query as I have it now:

```
SELECT SUM(SPRICE) AS Tot, MIN(SMIN) AS Min 
FROM 
   (SELECT COUNT(LS.SALEPRICE) AS SPRICE, MIN(LS.SALEPRICE) AS SMIN 
    FROM `linkshare` LS 
    WHERE LS.`PRODUCTNAME` LIKE 'DVS Men\'s Comanche Skate Shoe%' 
    UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(CJ.PRICE) AS SPRICE, MIN(CJ.PRICE) AS SMIN 
    FROM `cjfeeds` CJ 
    WHERE CJ.NAME LIKE 'DVS Men\'s Comanche Skate Shoe%' ) 
   AS xyz
```

My Questions: 
i am create index key for price field. how can i use this query?

Also how can i optimize my query performance?

My explain query is given below

[image: And here's how an explain looks:]

Please Advise

Comment: `possible_keys` NULL for your underlying tables suggests that you have no indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, no indexes are used. Put an index on LS.PRODUCTNAME and CJ.NAME.

Also suspect you want a UNION ALL, and probably COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(fieldname).

An index on Price is unlikely to help.

Long term it would probably be better to split off the product names into a different table, with the rows on the tables you have there referring to the id of the product table.

Comment: Not count(*) buddy. would be slower - count(fieldname) is better otherwise +1

Comment: But count(fieldname) will ignore NULL fields, which I suspect he might want included in the counts. Count(*) can be faster (although suspect in this case with a LIKE this won't be the case)

Comment: ok buddy. maybe a COALESCE would take care of that NULL condition however, yeah would create a further overhead.

Comment: @Kickstart i am change my table structure set index into PRODUCTNAME and NAME its also take 12 sec to 13 sec of loading time. because of my 2 tables contains 40 M records. so please help me any other ways to optimize my qyery

Comment: Could you add the new EXPLAIN results to your original post, along with the table declares? Further is there any way you can narrow down the search before resorting to doing a LIKE on a large VARCHAR (I presume) field?